# Custom loss function works even though dimensions mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm using Keras/TF with the following model:

```
conv = Conv2D(4, 3, activation = None, use_bias=True)(inputs)   
conv = Conv2D(2, 1, activation = None, use_bias=True)(conv)
model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss=keras.losses.mean_absolute_error)
```

In model.fit, I get an error saying:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_2 to have
>   shape (300, 320, 2) but got array with shape (300, 320, 1)

This is as expected because the targets are single channel images whereas the last layer in the model has 2 channels.

What I don't understand is why when I use a custom loss function:

```
def my_loss2(y_true, y_pred):
    return keras.losses.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

and compile the model:

```
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4), loss=my_loss2)
```

it **does** work (or at least, not giving the error). Is there any kind of automatic conversion/truncation going on?

I'm using TF (CPU) 1.12.0, and Keras 2.2.2

Sincerely,
Elad

Comment: This is interesting, are you sure there is nothing else that is changed other than the loss function, because adding a wrapper around the loss, shouldn't really change anything.

Comment: Which keras version are you using? I cannot confirm this for keras 2.2.2. `model.compile` doesn't give me an error for either of the losses. However, I do get an error for both of them when calling `model.fit`. In fact, in the code you are posting, `model.compile` has no notion of your target shape, so how should it detect that error?

Comment: Sorry I didn't state this in the post. The error occurs in model.fit of course (I'll update the post). I'm using keras 2.2.2 and tensorflow (cpu) 1.12.0, what version gave you consistent behavior?

Comment: @Marumba I just realized that the error I'm getting for the custom loss is different. It happened because of an inconsistency in the in the second last dimension that I was missing. If I fix that and all dimensions are the same, except for the last one, `fit` indeed passes without any error for custom loss. Apparently, there is some broadcasting going on for the last dimension, but that doesn't explain why the built-in loss isn't broadcasting... I'm assuming for built-in losses `fit` is doing some manual shape check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why is the behavior different for built-in and custom losses?

It turns out that Keras is performing an upfront shape check for built-in functions that are defined in the losses module.

In the source code of [`Model._standardize_user_data`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L643), which is called by `fit`, I found this comment:

> ```
> # If `loss_fn` is not a function (e.g. callable class)
> # or if it not in the `losses` module, then
> # it is a user-defined loss and we make no assumptions
> # about it.
> ```

In the code around that comment you can see that indeed, depending on the type of loss function (built-in or custom), the output shape is either passed to an inner call of `standardize_input_data` or not. If the output shape is passed, [`standardize_input_data`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L33) is raising the error message you are getting.

And I think this behavior makes some sense: Without knowing the implementation of a loss function, you cannot know its shape requirements. Someone may invent some loss function that needs different shapes. On the other hand, the [docs](https://keras.io/losses/) clearly say that the loss function's parameters must have the same shape:

> y_true: True labels. TensorFlow/Theano tensor.
>
> y_pred: Predictions. TensorFlow/Theano tensor of the same shape as y_true.

So I find this a little inconsistent...

### Why does your custom loss function work with incompatible shapes?

If you provide a custom loss, it may still work, even if the shapes do not perfectly match. In your case, where only the last dimension is different, I'm quite sure that [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/broadcasting) is what is happening. The last dimension of your targets will just be duplicated.

In many cases broadcasting is quite useful. Here, however, it is likely not since it hides a logical error.